# WorldPay Integration

Tags: e-commerce, worldpay

I have been asked to set up a demo site which calls out to WorldPay to authorise transactions.

We won't have a MerchantID or anything like that yet, is there a dummy service that you can call that is either on the internet at-large, or is downloadable and you can install locally?

I've obviously had a look around and so far come up with nothing - it's a straightforward answer so wondering if anyone on here knows off the top of their head?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Was a few years ago but as far as I remember:

If you (or your client) are going to be signing up with Worldpay then they provide both live and test accounts.
I seem to remember that you have to put a successful transaction through the test account before they will activate the live one for you.

Thier support dept used to be very helpful so I'd suggest just giving them a ring
It's in their interests to get you up and running so they can start charging you for it